# Seeking Guidance on Creating a Custom Moodle Theme from Scratch

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-theme

I'm relatively new to Moodle and eager to dive deeper into its capabilities. My current focus lies in crafting a custom theme entirely from scratch, rather than utilizing a child theme, for my Moodle site. However, I'm unsure where to begin. Could anyone point me in the right direction or offer some guidance on how to get started with theme development in Moodle?

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjoaD.png)

this is the folder structure
i have created this oneui theme dir inside theme

```
<?php

# defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();
$THEME->name = 'oneui';
$THEME->sheets = [];
$THEME->editor_sheets = [];
$THEME->parents = [''];
$THEME->enable_dock = false;
$THEME->yuicssmodules = array();
$THEME->rendererfactory = 'theme_overridden_renderer_factory';
$THEME->requiredblocks = '';
$THEME->addblockposition = BLOCK_ADDBLOCK_POSITION_FLATNAV;
$THEME->haseditswitch = true;
```

```
<?php
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();
$plugin->version = '2016102100';
$plugin->requires = '2016070700';
$plugin->component = 'theme_oneui';


this is the version.php
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

My current focus lies in crafting a custom theme entirely from scratch, rather than utilizing a child theme, for my Moodle site.